# what does activation function become in spiking neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

In common ANN, nodes are based on a activation function, like a sigmoid or tanh or ReLU. Updates of synaptic weight are based on the derivative of this function.

When node are represented with spiking neurons, what does activation function become ? how updates of synaptic weight are done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activation function would be inherent to the spiking model used.

Each [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_neuron_model)  have a different dynamic which will depend on the proper model and parameters used.